# Is there something odd with PowerShell and forwards slashes?

Tags: powershell

As far as I know, a forward slash is not a reserved keyword in PowerShell. But running the following in cmd pops up an about dialog

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:about
```

The same in PowerShell gives:

```
'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe' /command:about

You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '/' operator.
At line:1 char:54
+ 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe' /c <<<< ommand:about
```

What gives?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put an ampersand character in front of the command

```
&"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:about
```

Otherwise, it thinks you're trying to divide the string literal `"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe"` by something, but it doesn't know by what.